# Update discord.js bot without killing it

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots, restart

is there a way to update my discord bot's code without killing its process ?

Like if I change a single letter in a command code, do I have to restart the bot entirely to update it ? And what about non-command code ?

I'm restarting my bot to update/test the code a lot lately, and discord sent me a message saying my bot restarts too often.

Should i ignore the message, or do you have a solution for updating without restarting it?

Thanks.

Comment: I dont think so updating without restarting is possible because, once you start execution of your code, it creates a new process and it is not really possible to change the code in execution

Comment: No, it is not possible. Your client gets 1000 logins per day, make sure you write your code carefully and reduce the number of times you restart every 24 hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, if a command handler is created like this,

`index.js`

```js
const { Collection } = require("discord.js");

client.slash = new Collection();
const slashCommandFolders = fs.readdirSync("./slash");
for (const folder of slashCommandFolders) {
  const commandFiles = fs
    .readdirSync(`./slash/${folder}`)
    .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));
  for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./slash/${folder}/${file}`);
    client.slash.set(command.name, command);
  }
}
```

(command file is in `slash/<category>/<command_name>.js`)

`slash/general/ping.js`

```js
const { CommandInteraction } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: "ping",
  /**
   *
   * @param {CommandInteraction} i
   */
  execute(i) {
    i.reply({ content: "Pong" });
  },
};
```

(The interactionCreate event needs to be handled properly, but we will skip that here)

By creating such a reload command:

`src/admin/reload.js`

```js
const {
  CommandInteraction,
  Client,
  CommandInteractionOptionResolver,
} = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");

module.exports = {
  name: "reload",
  /**
   *
   * @param {CommandInteraction} i
   * @param {Client} client
   * @param {CommandInteractionOptionResolver} options
   */
  async execute(i, client, options) {
    const commandName = options.getString("command").toLowerCase();
    const command =
      i.client.slash.get(commandName) ||
      i.client.slash.find(
        (cmd) => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName)
      );

    if (!command)
      return i.reply({ content: "No command found", ephemeral: true });
    const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync("./slash");
    const folderName = commandFolders.find((folder) =>
      fs.readdirSync(`./slash/${folder}`).includes(`${command.name}.js`)
    );
    delete require.cache[
      require.resolve(`../${folderName}/${command.name}.js`)
    ];

    try {
      const newCommand = require(`../${folderName}/${command.name}.js`);
      i.client.slash.set(newCommand.name, newCommand);
      i.reply({ content: "reloaded", ephemeral: true });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      i.reply({ content: "reload failed", ephemeral: true });
    }
  },
};
```

We can apply changes without restarting bot. so dapper system